# A peculiar newbie debugging

Tags: php

It is one of the things I should have the know how but it really bugs. I have a large script which automates several tasks. It starts with uploading of files after which data from the files are extracted and then imported into mysql. In debugging mode it works perfectly but on my web front-end, execution stops after the data from the uploaded file is extracted. It never reaches the importation into database phase.

I realised that I had used this particular code below which I hold suspect:

```
$newFilePath = $upload_directory."/".$inFileName;
//opening the input file
if($inFileName != "")
$inputFile = fopen($newFilePath,"r");
else exit(1);
if(!$inputFile)
exit(0);
while(!feof($inputFile)) {
```

It is obvious that the exit() as used terminates the scripts thereby leaving out the lines that is handling the import of data into mysql.WIth the above, the upload works and the data separation carried out but the import never got executed. After some study I reviewed that portion by doing something quite appropriate like:

```
if (file_exists($inFileName)){
        $inputFile = fopen($newFilePath,"r");
    }
    else {
        echo "No file found ";
    }

    if (is_readable($inputFile)){
        echo " ";
    }else {
        echo 'The file could not be read';
    }
```

Now this piece of code review did not get me anyway as the upload is not even possible.

Now my problem is to fix this little portion of the code so I get the other parts of the script after it to do the import. It has been a nightmare for a beginner like me. I would appreciate if someone could review the above portion in a different way. I hope to see something that is similar or different but valid. I have learnt tougher stuff than this but this is simply nuts. I hope someone could understand my explanation. Thanks

### New Edit.

```
if (is_array($inFilesArray)) {
foreach($inFilesArray as $inFileName) {

    $numLines = 1;

    $newFilePath = $upload_directory."/".$inFileName;
    //opening the input file
    if (file_exists($newFilePath)){

        if (is_readable($newFilePath)){

            $inputFile = fopen($newFilePath,"r");
        }
    } else {
        echo "File not accessable";
    }

    //reading the inFile line by line and outputting the line if searchCriteria is met
    while(!feof($inputFile)) {
        $line = fgets($inputFile);
        $lineTokens = explode(',',$line);
        // Assign Device ID
        switch ($lineTokens[0]){
            case "IMEI 358998018395510\r\n":
                $device_id = 1;
                break;
            case "IMEI 352924028650492\r\n":
                $device_id = 3;
                break;
            case '$GPVTG':
                $device_id = 2;
                break;

        }
        if(in_array($lineTokens[0],$searchCriteria)) {
            if (fwrite($outFile4, $device_id . "," .$line)===FALSE){
                echo "Problem writing files\n";
            }
            $time = $lineTokens[1];
            $date = $lineTokens[9];
            $numLines++;
        }

        // Defining search criteria for $GPGGA
        $lineTokens = explode(' ',$line);
        $searchCriteria2 = array('OutCell');
        if(in_array($lineTokens[0],$searchCriteria2)) {
            if (fwrite($outFile5, $time.",".$date."\n")===FALSE){
                echo "Problem writing to file\n";
            }
        }
    }

    fclose($inputFile);
}
```

### Entire Script

```
<?php

#This script has threee parts: The first handles the uploaded files while the second   part retrieves all RMCs and Handover dates and the 3rd handles importation of the data  into their respective table in mysql database.

# This part uploads text files
include 'setamainfunctions.php';

if (isset($_POST['uploadfiles'])) {
$number_of_uploaded_files = 0;
$number_of_moved_files = 0;
$uploaded_files = array();
$upload_directory = dirname(__file__) . '/Uploads/';
//echo count($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'])." uploaded ";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']); $i++) {
    //$number_of_file_fields++;
    if ($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][$i] != '') { //check if file field  empty or not
        $number_of_uploaded_files++;
        $uploaded_files[] = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][$i];
        //if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'])){
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'][$i],  $upload_directory . $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][$i])) {
            $number_of_moved_files++;
        }

    }

}

echo "Number of files submitted $number_of_uploaded_files . <br/>";
echo "Number of successfully moved files $number_of_moved_files . <br/>";
echo "File Names are <br/>" . implode("<br/>", $uploaded_files)."\n";
echo "</br>";
echo "<p> Please find the processed RMCs and corresponding handovers as text files named:outputRMCs.txt and OutputHandovers.txt in the Setapro project root folder</p>";
/*  echo "<br/>";
 echo "<br/>";
 echo "<p> Result of Mobile GPRMCs Transaction";
 //echo "Total entries imported:.$numlines . <br/>";
 echo "Data extraction and import mobile mobile GPRMCs successfuly completed";
 echo "<br/>";
 echo "<br/>";
 echo "<p> Result of Handover Transaction";
 //echo "Total entries imported:.$numlines . <br/>";
 echo "Data extraction and imports for mobile handovers successfuly completed";*/
```

}

```
# This is the start of a script which accepts the uploaded into another array of it   own for extraction of GPRMCs and handover dates.

$searchCriteria = array('$GPRMC');

//creating a reference for multiple text files in an array

/*if(isset($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']))
 $_FILES['uploadedFile'] = '';
 }else {
echo "yes";
}*/
$inFilesArray = ($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);

//$inFiles =    fopen($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'], 'r');

//This opens a textfile for writing operation and puts all the entries from the      multiple text files into one distinct textfile
if( ($outFile4 = fopen("outputRMCs.txt", "a")) === false ){
echo " ";
}
$outFile5 = fopen("outputHandovers.txt", "a");

//processing individual files in the array called $inFilesArray via foreach loop

if (is_array($inFilesArray)) {
foreach($inFilesArray as $inFileName) {

    $numLines = 1;

    $newFilePath = $upload_directory."/".$inFileName;
    $correctFile = false;
    //opening the input file
    if (file_exists($newFilePath)){

        if (is_readable($newFilePath)){

            $inputFile = fopen($newFilePath,"r");
            $correctFile = true;
        }
    }
    if (!$correctFile)
    echo "File not accessable";

    //reading the inFile line by line and outputting the line if  searchCriteria is met
    while(!feof($inputFile)) {
        $line = fgets($inputFile);
        $lineTokens = explode(',',$line);
        // Assign Device ID
        switch ($lineTokens[0]){
            case "IMEI 358998018395510\r\n":
                $device_id = 1;
                break;
            case "IMEI 352924028650492\r\n":
                $device_id = 3;
                break;
            case '$GPVTG':
                $device_id = 2;
                break;

        }
        if(in_array($lineTokens[0],$searchCriteria)) {
            if (fwrite($outFile4, $device_id . "," .$line)===FALSE){
                echo "Problem writing files\n";
            }
            $time = $lineTokens[1];
            $date = $lineTokens[9];
            $numLines++;
        }

        // Defining search criteria for $GPGGA
        $lineTokens = explode(' ',$line);
        $searchCriteria2 = array('OutCell');
        if(in_array($lineTokens[0],$searchCriteria2)) {
            if (fwrite($outFile5, $time.",".$date."\n")===FALSE){
                echo "Problem writing to file\n";
            }
        }
    }

    fclose($inputFile);
}

//close the in files
fflush($outFile4);
fflush($outFile5);
}


fclose($outFile4);
fclose($outFile5);

#End of script for handling extraction

# This is the start of the script which imports the text file data into mysql  database   and does the necessary conversion.

$FilePath1 = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/setapro/outputRMCs.txt';

if (is_readable($FilePath1)) {
$handle = fopen($FilePath1, "r");
rmc_handoverHandler($handle);
echo "";
fclose($handle);
} else {
echo 'The file could not be read';
```

}

```
#Begining of script to handle imports into handover table

$FilePath2 = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/setapro/outputHandovers.txt';
if (is_readable($FilePath2)) {
$handle = fopen($FilePath2, "r");
mobile_handoverHandler($handle);
echo "";
fclose($handle);
} else {
echo 'The file could not be read';
}

#End of script for handling imports into handover table

?>
```

Comment: What is your script max_execution_time set to in php.ini ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you want to do something more like this...

```
$newFilePath = $upload_directory."/".$inFileName;
$goodFile=false;

//Does the file exist?
if (file_exists($newFilePath)){ 

    //If so, is it readable?
    if (is_readable($newFilePath)){ 

        //if it exists, and it readable, open it
        $inputFile = file_get_contents($newFilePath); 

        //Don't display the error when done because file is good
        $goodFile=true;

        //Do Other stuff with file contents

    }

} 

if (!goodFile) echo "File Access Error";
```

You want to use newFilePath as it contains the path as well as the file name. The fact that you are checking for the file's existence and readability without also passing the file's path (only the file name) may be the cause of your issues.

**UPDATE**

```
try {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']); $i++) {
        //$number_of_file_fields++;
        if ($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][$i] != '') { 
            $number_of_uploaded_files++;
            $uploaded_files[] = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][$i];
            //if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'])){
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'][$i],  $upload_directory . $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][$i])) {
                $number_of_moved_files++;
            }

        }
    } 
} catch (exception $e){ 
    echo "General Error"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your insightful reply. Instead of the get_file_content... I want to do $inputFile = fopen($newFilePath,"r"); Is this not possible? I want to open and read from it

Comment: I suggest using file_get_contents(). It's faster even thoug they'd both get the job done.

Comment: What if the file isn't readable? It just fails silently. You should do  `if (file_exists(...) && is_readable(...))`

Comment: Good point. Sloppy error on my part. Code updated to reflect that.

Comment: Sorry to bother you guys. I have done the changes as suggested but in vain. let me edit my post by adding the important aspect so you you can see what i may be doing wrong. thanks

Comment: Please do.. and let us know exactly what is happening.

Comment: I see the update... what is actually happening when you try this?

Comment: Just finished editing the post. @Dutche, I see you have made some changes

Comment: The changes are just to catch the error when the file is not readable as well.

Comment: What is happening now is: The files get uploaded and the data from them get extracted and written to new files but the data does not get imported into mysql. Usually it echoes the number of file submitted etc but it echos "0" and took a long time to respond. Is abnormal.

Comment: Do the files are being uploaded, opened, read, processed, and appropriate output get wrriten to another file? That seems to be working OK - so the part we were initially troubleshooting is working?  I don't see any echo statement in your code, other than errors - If you're having an issue with mySQL, you should post that question (and relevant code) in a new question, as you will be more likely to attract the people to best help you.

Comment: The output from the uploading upto the processing of the data is working correctly though it times out returning 0 instead echoing the the "the no of files submitted" It appears the scripts does not still executed the remaining lines that handled the imports into the database. Is strange

Comment: Without seeing all of the code, I'm not sure how I can help you.. I don't see any code where you are echo'ing the # of files submitted.

Comment: Yes the part we were initially troubleshooting is ok and I remain grateful to you guys. I strongly feel it is a php issue maybe am not explaining better. What baffles me is that, if I run only the script path in my address bar and not from a link on a webpage, it works and displays the result perfectly.

Comment: The more you can post, the better.

Comment: I have just post it all though there are some function calls which i did not include but hope this serves.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you try putting the entire `for(){}` loop in a `try{...} catch (exception $e){echo "General Error";}`

Comment: I would try that though not sure how php handles it but would refer it. sorry do you mean starting from "foreach"? am sure i understand you full either

Comment: oops! I meant am not sure I understand you fully either.

Comment: It is 0:39 Finish time. I do not wish to leave you but beg to take a break. If you drop anything I would be happy to pick it up as early as 3 or so. many thanks for your support.

Comment: Hello Dutchie, I have seen your update, thanks. That portion is notcatching any exception. When running from my webpage  via a link it still  returns "0"  after a long processing time. Am still reviewing the script.

Comment: There's gotta be a typo or something in one of the variables. The fact that your processes are being performed leads me to believe the `$number_of` variables are being incremented. Can you try putting `echo $number_of_moved_files;` and `echo $number_of_uploaded_files` after they are incremented?

Comment: Finally I got it sorted. Two things I reviewed; The first initial problem you assisted in troubleshooting and the while loop just after it.I added 1. if ($inFileName!="" && is_readable($newFilePath)){ and 2. while($inFileName && !feof($inputFile)) {. Those where the additions. Thanks for your assistance. With this situation, my debugging skill were horned.